# Change default search at VisualStudio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

There are 2 search UIs in VS2019.
How do I make this one my default if I pres global hotkeys:
[image]

Comment: Use CTRL+SHIFT+F

Comment: Or re-assign the CTRL+F to the command "Edit.FindinFiles" - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6THok.png - I wouldn't recommend it